# Trying to manually add item in a ListView tied to a custom cursor adapter

Tags: android, listview, cursor, adapter, android-cursoradapter

I need a little help for the redaction of a class. I want to add some item in my listView, and to do that I use a custom adapter found in this forum, but modified for my use :

```
public class AdvertisingAdapter extends cCursorAdapter  {

    private static final String ADMOB_PUBLISHER_ID = "YOUR_ADMOB_ID_HERE";

    private final Activity activity;
    private final cCursorAdapter delegate;
    Context context;

    static int rec = 15;

    public AdvertisingAdapter(Activity activity, cCursorAdapter delegate, Context context, Cursor cursor)
    {
        super(context, cursor, 0);
        this.activity = activity;
        this.delegate = delegate;
        this.context = context;
        delegate.registerDataSetObserver(new DataSetObserver()
        {
            @Override
            public void onChanged()
            {
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onInvalidated()
            {
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        if (position == 0 || position % rec == 0)
        {
            j = j + 1 ;

            if (convertView instanceof AdView)
            {
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                return convertView;
            }
            else
            {
                AdView adView = new AdView(context);
                // Disable focus for sub-views of the AdView to avoid problems with
                // trackpad navigation of the list.
                for (int i = 0; i < adView.getChildCount(); i++)
                {
                    adView.getChildAt(i).setFocusable(false);
                }
                adView.setFocusable(false);
                // Default layout params have to be converted to ListView compatible
                // params otherwise there will be a ClassCastException.
                float density = activity.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
                int height = Math.round(AdSize.BANNER.getHeight() * density);
                AbsListView.LayoutParams params
                        = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(AbsListView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        height);
                adView.setLayoutParams(params);
                AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
                adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111");
                adView.setAdSize(com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize.BANNER);
                adView.loadAd(adRequest);

                notifyDataSetChanged();

                return adView;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Log.i ("TEST AD ADAPTER", String.valueOf(j)
                    + " " + String.valueOf(position)
                    + " " + String.valueOf(getNbreAd())
                    + " " + String.valueOf(getNbrePos(position))
                    + " " + String.valueOf(getCount()));

            return delegate.getView(position - getNbrePos(position), convertView, parent);

        }
    }

    public int getNbreAd(){
        int l = delegate.getCount();
        return (l / rec) + 1;

    }

    public int getNbrePos(int position){
        int k = (position/rec) + 1;
        return k;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return delegate.getCount() + getNbreAd();
    }


    @Override
     public Object getItem(int i)
{
    return delegate.getItem(i - 1);
}

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i)
    {
        return delegate.getItemId(i - 1);
    }


    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount()
    {
        return delegate.getViewTypeCount() + 1;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position)
    {
        return position == 0 ? delegate.getViewTypeCount()
                : delegate.getItemViewType(position - 1);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areAllItemsEnabled()
    {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position)
    {
        return position != 0 && delegate.isEnabled(position - 1);
    }
}
```

My cCursorAdapter :

```
public class cCursorAdapter extends android.widget.CursorAdapter {

DataHelper mDBHelper;


public cCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor, int flags) {
        super(context, cursor, 0);

    }

    // The newView method is used to inflate a new view and return it,
    // you don't bind any data to the view at this point.
    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {

        return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_result2, parent, false);
    }

    // The bindView method is used to bind all data to a given view
    // such as setting the text on a TextView.
    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor){

        // Find fields to populate in inflated template
        TextView nameResult = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nameResult2);
        TextView ageG = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ageG2);
        TextView nbreJoueur = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nbreJoueur2);
        TextView timeResult = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.time2);
        ImageView placeGD = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.placeD2);
        TextView IDR2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.IDR2);

        // Extract properties from cursor
        String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("name"));
        String place = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("place"));
        int ageMin = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("agemin"));
        int ageMax = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("agemax"));
        int nbreMin = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("nbremin"));
        int nbreMax = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("nbremax"));
        int time = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("time"));
        final int ID = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id"));

        // Populate fields with extracted properties
        nameResult.setText(name);
        ageG.setText(String.valueOf(ageMin) + " - " + String.valueOf(ageMax));
        nbreJoueur.setText(String.valueOf(nbreMin) + " - " + String.valueOf(nbreMax));
        timeResult.setText(String.valueOf(time));
        IDR2.setText(String.valueOf(ID));
        if (place.equals("extérieur")) {
            Drawable placeD = MainActivity.mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_wb_sunny_black_24dp);
            placeGD.setImageDrawable(placeD);
        } else if (place.equals("intérieur")){
            Drawable placeD = MainActivity.mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_event_seat_black_24dp);
            placeGD.setImageDrawable(placeD);
        } else if (place.equals("partout")) {
            Drawable placeD = MainActivity.mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_explore_black_24dp);
            placeGD.setImageDrawable(placeD);
        }

        //Cacher l'ID (c'est pas joli)
        IDR2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    }




//Override the convert to string sequence
@Override
public CharSequence convertToString(Cursor cursor){
    final int colIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("name");
    return cursor.getString(colIndex);
}

@Override
public Cursor runQueryOnBackgroundThread(CharSequence constraint)
{
    Cursor currentCursor = null;

    if (getFilterQueryProvider() != null)
    {
        return getFilterQueryProvider().runQuery(constraint);
    }

    String args = "";

    if (constraint != null)
    {
        args = constraint.toString();
    }

    //Initialize that shit
    mDBHelper = new DataHelper(MainActivity.mContext);
    currentCursor = mDBHelper.getNameCursor(args);

    return currentCursor;
}


 }
```

In a certain way, it works. But when I swipe the listView too fast, I have this error :

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                                                          at com.tanoshi.traveler.doctorgamesfree.cCursorAdapter.bindView(cCursorAdapter.java:57)
                                                                                      at android.widget.CursorAdapter.getView(CursorAdapter.java:254)
                                                                                      at com.tanoshi.traveler.doctorgamesfree.AdvertisingAdapter.getView(AdvertisingAdapter.java:102)
```

I think it is becausemy listView try to load an item in a view which is not loaded. 
How can I do to fix this ?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Please post code of cCursorAdapter.java

Comment: @sJy See my edit :)

Comment: Check whether list_result2.xml contains all TextView's initialized in your bindView() method. Post your xml.

Comment: Everything load perfectly, if I swipe slowly my listView everything work just fine. But when I am too fast, my application stop working.

Comment: I meant when a swipe for a short time, everything work, but if iI swipe for too long, it stop working.